# Automatic holding page for any sites pointing to my IP

Tags: apache, virtual, host

I have loads of domains all pointing to my servers IP but because they are just holding domains I haven't configured them in WHM / Apache. Therefore they just get "can't display website" messages when visited.

Is it possible to set up rule (or whatever! (Virtual Host?)) that will point any domains not configured on my server (but pointed to it) to a generic holding page?

I was thinking I could use a VirtualHost like this:

```
<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
DocumentRoot /www/path/to/holding/account/
ServerName *
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope that makes sense!
Thanks

Comment: This is probably more a question for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I looked at questions posted on both sites and saw that similar questions were being asked and answered on both. So I tossed a coin! If others agree though then I will delete this and repost on Server Fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the `ServerName` directive.

From my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` - note that only the DocumentRoot directive is *needed*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this effect any existing virtualhosts? Should I add the to the start or end of the virtual hosts?